# how to inizialize user control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html

I have created an .acsx file that is an user control I need in a .aspx file.
I have to put this user control in a panel and I have to do it in vb.net.

In the .aspx I put the tag

`<%@ Register src="events.ascx" tagname="ucEvents" tagprefix="uc1" %>`

so what can I do to create that kind of userControl in my code?
I've tried

```
Dim uc As New UserControl
```

or

```
Dim uc As New uc1
```

or

```
Dim uc As New ucEvents
```

But it doesn't work.

I only need to know how to create and initialize my user control so then I can do

```
panel.Controls.Add(uc)
```

Comment: What do you mean, "it doesn't work"?

Comment: uc1 and ucEvents are 'undefined'

Comment: `Dim count As Decimal = 1
   
    Protected Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        count = count + 1
        Dim uc As New UserControl
        
        uc.ID = "ucEvents" & count
        panel.Controls.Add(uc)
    End Sub`
Here's the code, but when I execute it nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `ClassName` of your user control you defined. Check the .ascx.cs for the class name.

```
Dim uc As New MyUserControlType

panel.Controls.Add(uc)
```

.aspx markup

This markup can be used only to refer the user control in .aspx page and not in code behind

```
<%@ Register src="events.ascx" tagname="ucEvents" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<uc1:ucEvents ID="myCtrl" runat="server" />
```

Comment: It isn't so easy: the number of user control I have to put in the panel is undefined so I don't know how many user control I have to put in my .aspx
When the user clicks a button then a new user control is put in the panel, so I need to inizialize it in my code behind